# Laravel make the browser renders a dynamic image

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm using dynamic image generator [**simple-qrcode**](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode). It works fine as `img` `src`. However, when I try to directly access, *for example* `site.dev/qr/some-text/60`, the image from the client's address bar it returns encoded text not an image.

The following is the action method:

```
public function qr($txt='None',$size=32)
    {
        return QrCode::format('png')->size($size)->generate(urldecode($txt));
    }
```

The following is the route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/generator/qr/{txt?}/{size?}', 'GeneratorController@qr')->where(['txt', '(.*)/']);
```

I have tried to add `.png` hoping the browser consider it as an image i.e. `site.dev/qr/some-text/60/qr.png`,  to the route, but it does not work too, as the following:

```
Route::get('/generator/qr/{txt?}/{size?}/qr.png', 'GeneratorController@qr')->where(['txt', '(.*)/']);
```

The application is running using PHP7.1.3 as fastcgi on Nginx 1.10.3 / Windows10 64 bit. The following is the virtual host settings of Nginx:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  site.dev;
        location /{
            root   C:/Users/Said/Desktop/Project/laravel/site/public;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        error_page  404              /404.html;        
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/Users/Said/Desktop/Project/laravel/site/public/$fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

            include        fastcgi_params;
        }        
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be solved by creating a custom Response with the correct headers:

```
use Response;
//....
public function qr($txt='None',$size=32)
    {
        $qr = QrCode::format('png')->size($size)->generate(urldecode($txt));    
        $response = Response::make($qr, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", "image/png");
        return $response;
     }
```

Comment: Very good, but we have to mention to add `use Response` in the controller's class.